# Remove grey border from nav hover menu

Tags: css

My buddy is putting a website together, and he is wanting to remove the grey border from around the navigation menu objects when they are hovered and/or active pages.  I can't for the life of me find what needs to be changed in his mess of code.  Not even sure what snippets to post here.  If anyone can figure out I would greatly appreciate it
http://cf5s.suspected.org/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following rule is what's producing the box:

```
#nav li:hover, #nav li.current_page_item,
#nav li.current_page_parent, #nav li.current-menu-item,
#nav li.current-menu-ancestor {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Either remove that style, or alter the way it's being applied to get rid of the "border" effect. [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) and Firefox are your friends for tracking down stuff like this (Chrome has some decent tools too, if I recall correctly, but I'm a Firefox guy).